# Open webpage then click on a button - script

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can automatically click on a webpage upon when it loads either through Group Policy or a script I can run through task scheduler?

Essentially staff members login to the computer, it opens up a webpage automatically through GPO where they can then click the Microsoft button on the webpage to sign in automatically (single sign on).
I was wondering if there was a way where I can make it automatically press on the microsoft button. I can get the queryselector and run it with a .click() command in the console and it works but I'm not sure how to automate this process.

I have seen suggestions like tampermonkey and other extensions but I need a solution where I can just deploy to all computers/users remotely like a script of some sort.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: If you want to do this with a script separate from the browser, it's has to be something OS-specific. On Macs you would use AppleScript, for instance.

Comment: If you manage your users' computers, you should be able to deploy a browser extension to all of them.

Comment: Why not just change the start url of the clients?

Comment: Tried that but the start URL is like this:  (but like a longer version so it seems to be click/user specific as it contains unique tokens i assume.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/42c0e804-975e-40ee-9a43-93fb482e1b68/oauth2/authorize?client_id=06dd8445-8123-40a2-9bde-84620b2137a8&redirect_uri=https%3AJqd71lyn75A&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.12.2.0&sso_reload=true

I can deploy a browser extension to all but I can deploy custom edits to each one to work with its intended purpose.